# Redirecting postname.html to postid.html

Tags: redirect

I want to convert my `postname.html` to `postid.html`

My link in wordpress (custom permalink structure:)

```
 /%postname%.html
```

And I write in `.htaccess`

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Now I want to add `postid` in last link as `www.xxxx.com/123.html`.
I add this code:

```
/%post_id%.html
```

But when I press on any link in google I have error page not found.

How can I do that to convert my link  without loss my link in google?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is what you are looking for, but putting this in your head does a redirect.  There's a JS version where a string can be adapted before been sent to that URL as well.

```
<meta HTTP-EQUIV="REFRESH" content="0; url=http://www.yourdomain.com/index.html">
```

JS:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
window.location = "http://www.google.com/"
//-->
</script>
```

Comment: its not work >look my link www.morzak.net/contactus.html ( contactus its postname)i want to convert it www.morzak.net/1234.html (1234 its post id ) custom permalink structure  > how can i do that to convert my link without loss my link in google thanks > i need redirect from .htaccess or any way >

Answer (score 0):

In HTML:
`<meta HTTP-EQUIV="REFRESH" content="0; url=/postid.html">`

In Javascript:
`<script>
window.location = "http://www.yourdomain.com/../postid.html"
</script>`

In PHP:
`<?php 
header('http://www.yourdomain.com/../postid.html'); 
?>`

If you would like a .htaccess example, please comment saying so.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way:
`redirect postname.html postid.html`

That's .htaccess